# Unable to upload and display text from database

Tags: php, html, mysql

Error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'display.php on line 12

Code:

```html
<?php
mysql_connect('com', '1', 'P');
mysql_select_db('add');
$query =mysql_query('select * from addimage');
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) )
{
echo '<div style="min-width:300px;height:100px;border:red 5px;float:left;">''<a href='.$row['url'].>'.$row['name'].'</a>''</div>';
}

?>
```

These php code uploaded url  but not name add.php

```html
<?php
$servername = "com";
$username = "1";
$password = "P";
$dbname = "add";
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$URL=$_POST['url'];
$NAME=$_POST['name'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO addimage (url,name)VALUES ('$URL','$NAME')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    include('done.php');
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

HERE IS MY FORM

```html
<form action="add.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <label>Image URL<input type="url" name="url"><br></label><br>
   <label>Your Name <input typr="text" name="text"><br></label>
   <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

I want to Display name stored in table 'name'
and link it to url stored in field in 'url' in same column

```
|  id     |      url          |   name   |
|1        | http:\\stack.com  |   me     |
```

I want to display me and link it to http:\stack.com
(Imagine I have 10000 url and I want to display only unvisited url) of the user

This code are written in a protected page seen after logging in

Comment: In the 1st Question u missed a quote there... do this...
`echo '<div style="min-width:300px;height:100px;border:red 5px;float:left;">''<a href='.$row['url'].'>'.$row['name'].'</a>''</div>';`

and in the secind question u gave the textbox name as TEXT and getting it through NAME... hwz it possible... change any of those.. they should be same...

`<label>Your Name <input type="text" name="name"><br></label>`

Do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1)

how about

```
echo "<div style='min-width:300px;height:100px;border:red 5px;float:left;'> <a href={$row['url']}>{$row['name']}</a></div>";
```

OR

```
echo '<div style="min-width:300px;height:100px;border:red 5px;float:left;">'.'<a href='.$row['url'].'>'.$row['name'].'</a>'.'</div>';
```

Q2)

In the form you have

```
<input typr="text" name="text">
```

but you are getting $_POST['name']. So either use $_POST['text'] or change input's name from **text** to **name**

Oh and I noticed its *typr* instead of *type*

Answer (score 0):

Q1 is just a parse error.
You should really know how to handle these, before you continue with anything else.

```
echo '<div style="min-width:300px;height:100px;border:red 5px;float:left;"> <a href="' . $row['url'] . '">' . $row['name'] . '</a> </div>';
```

Every ' you open, you have to close.  Look carefully.  I am a forgiving man; parsers are not; any comma, apostrophe... must me done right.